# Why all dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged events trigger only after button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a simple ASP.NET Application. And On one of my pages all `dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged` events trigger only after I click save button.

This is part of my code behidn:

```
protected void ddlTimekeeperOffice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckUniqueCombination();
        }

        protected void ddlTkprDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckUniqueCombination();
        }

        protected void ddlTkprSummaryTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckUniqueCombination();
        }
```

this is 3 dropdowns

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trTimekeeperRow.Visible = true;
        }
```

and a save button.

When I select anything in dropdowns > Nothing happens
Then I click save button and before save_click it goes through every ddl_selectedindexchanged.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `AutoPostBack` property of the dropdown controls is `true`.

Comment: O   M  G   !!! I've copied all ddls from other page before set this to true=) That's so stupid! =))) Спасибо ;)